# windows and linux, both on different drives. Any performance issues?

Tags: linux, windows-7, performance, multi-boot

I dual-booted windows and Linux, in a different way. The way I did it is by having both operating systems on different hard drives. I am able to switch back and forth as the Linux one is installed on UEFI while windows boots on normal BIOS, so enabling UEFI boots into Linux and disabling it boots into windows.
Will this cause any bottlenecks or performance issues? Or any other problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no technical problem with this method. I suggest
[disabling fast startup](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup)
in Windows, which is always a good idea when having multiple
operating system on the computer.

The biggest problem is for you - the awkwardness in the fact that you need
to enter the BIOS in order to switch between Windows and Linux.

Comment: I think I am fine with switching to OS in the BIOS, I'll be using Linux 99% of the time, just need windows around 4 to 5 times a year...

Comment: You could perhaps get by using a Windows virtual machine.